# Javascript Object properties (in Node) not getting logged or logged with a different name

Tags: node.js, formidable

I am using Node's formidable package from felixge. This is more a Javascript question than one specific to formidable, or so I think.

If I do a console.log on MYOBJ, I get the following:

```
{ file1: 
  File {
   domain: null,
   _events: {},
   _eventsCount: 0,
   _maxListeners: undefined,
   size: 62464,
   path: 'myDir/upload_e79d8d551721e2f399afbc39d5d5eaab.doc',
   name: 'somefile.doc',
   type: 'application/msword',
   hash: null,
   lastModifiedDate: Thu May 19 2016 20:22:24 GMT+0530 (IST),
   _writeStream: 
    WriteStream {
      _writableState: [Object],
      writable: true,
      domain: null,
      _events: {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      path: 'uploadDir/upload_1e0e9625e27f5c5172eaf5d18172f946.doc',
      fd: null,
      flags: 'w',
      mode: 438,
      start: undefined,
      pos: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 62464,
      closed: true } } }
```

If I do a console.log, like so:

```
for (var filename in MYOBJ)  
  console.log(MYOBJ[filename]);
```

I get the following:

```
{ size: 62464,
  path: 'myDir/upload_e79d8d551721e2f399afbc39d5d5eaab.doc',
  name: 'somefile.doc',
  type: 'application/msword',
  mtime: '2016-05-19T14:52:24.129Z' }
```

My obvious question is:

Why are the other properties of "file1" not displayed? May be they are not the Object's "ownProperty"? Even so, why does "lastModifiedDate" become "mtime?"

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using?

Comment: @Krzysztof Safjanowski. Node version is v4.4.4

Comment: It would be nice if the person down-voting gave some justification so I know what is unclear, why it is not useful and what more research I should have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess ... probably implementation for `cosnole.log` uses [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) and can list all non-enumerable values

```
var o = {}
Object.defineProperty(o, 'nonEnumerableValue', {value: 1})


console.log(o) // {}
console.log(o.nonEnumerableValue) // 1
```

Comment: I thought so too as you can see in the concluding statement in my question (language modified later, slightly). But, I thought that there is hasOwnProperty method for this purpose but then console.log may be using that... thats what you are saying? Makes sense. But what about the property name change...  "LastmodifiedDate" becoming "mtime?"

Comment: Both console.log are in Node. But your reference link is VERY useful.  I will accept your answer, if nothing else comes thru just because of the link provided. Very informative.